# What to do when my manager insists I have a dog?

Tags: communication, manager

I recently had a meeting with my manager. They were very insistent that I had a dog, asking how the dog was doing, talking about their dog, saying that her dog was playing up and that I no doubt know how this is.

I have never talked to her about pets. She clearly doesn't remember our conversations that well. Whoever has a dog in this conversation is not me.

I wasn't sure if it was polite to correct her. That would have been a bit awkward. It's not financially realistic for me to purchase a dog to keep up the illusion. I also have my end of year review soon, and it would be kinda annoying to have a social conflict with her over a mythical dog. What should I do?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because come on now.

Comment: Did you tell them you don't have a dog?

Comment: What did you tell your manager when she said that you already had a dog ?

Comment: Normally, it would not hurt someone's feeling if you politely tell them that you don't have a dog and they are mistaken. (For example, you can tell the manager that maybe, someone else has a dog and she mistakes you for that person for some reason. It happens all the time...)  The longer you wait to tell them the truth and keep playing along to give them the illusion that you had a dog, the more awkward it is to correct them later on because they may think that you are playing them up all this time by not telling them the truth...

Comment: I felt too awkward to tell them I had a dog in the meeting. I was pretty surprised and we were discussing heavy stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming this is genuine, the next time it comes up I'd just say

> "I'm really sorry I don't have one, you must be thinking of someone else...."

and then ask a question about their dog, so they have a "way out" without having to justify how they thought you had one, why they're mistaken, etc, etc

Comment: Thanks, it is sadly real, and I will tell them.